# CentOS 6 : MinGW32 Installations

Tags: centos, shared-libraries, mingw, cross-platform

When issue the following command:

```
 yum search mingw
```

it is showing following pacages which is missing many packages

```
mingw32-filesystem.noarch : MinGW base filesystem and environment
mingw32-runtime.noarch : MinGW Windows cross-compiler runtime
mingw32-binutils.x86_64 : MinGW Windows binutils
mingw32-gcc.x86_64 : MinGW Windows cross-compiler (GCC) for C
mingw32-gcc-c++.x86_64 : MinGW Windows cross-compiler for C++
mingw32-w32api.noarch : Win32 header files and stubs
mingw32-cpp.x86_64 : MinGW Windows cross-C Preprocessor
mingw32-nsis.x86_64 : Nullsoft Scriptable Install System
```

There are many package which required to be installed are:

```
mingw-libgcrypt
mingw-libgcrypt-devel
mingw-libgcrypt11
mingw-libgpg-error
mingw-libgpg-error-devel
mingw-libgpg-error0
mingw-liblzma-devel 
mingw-liblzma5 
mingw-pthreads 
mingw-runtime 
mingw-w32api 
mingw-xz 
mingw-zlib
mingw-zlib1
```

Somehow I able to install the following packages:

```
mingw32-inutils.x86_64    2.19.51.0.14-1.el6.art   @atomic
mingw32-cpp.x86_64        4.4.6-4.el6              installed
mingw32-filesystem.noarch 63-5.el6                 installed
mingw32-nsis.x86_64       2.46-2.el6               @atomic
mingw32-runtime.noarch    3.18-2.el6.2             installed
mingw32-w32api.noarch     3.14-2.el6.2             installed
```

When I tried to install the mingw32-pthreads then the error message shown as:

```
 rpm -i mingw32-pthreads-2.8.0-10.el6.6.noarch.rpm

 warning: mingw32-pthreads-2.8.0-10.el6.6.noarch.rpm: Header 
          V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 192a7d7d: NOKEY
 error: Failed dependencies:
         mingw32(libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll) is needed by 
         mingw32-pthreads-2.8.0-10.el6.6.noarch
```

When tried to install mingw32-gcc it fails due to require mingw32-pthreads

I have tried web and not found any soultion. I think only solution would be re-compile all the libraries on system. But I don't how to do that, download location and other things. Kindly provide a detailed brief for installation of mingw32 and mingw64 also